# Transform Start/End date to sequence of dates in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to do something which I thought was fairly simple but so far I have not found a way of realizing it without a overly convoluted formula.

My table1 would look as follows:

```
Personal ID Start     End       Code
1           1/2/2023  1/5/2023  V
2           1/1/2023  1/2/2023  S
1           1/10/2023 1/15/2023 S
```

And from this table I want to create this:

```
Personal ID 1-Jan 2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan 5-Jan 6-Jan 7-Jan 8-Jan 9-Jan 10-Jan 11-Jan 12-Jan 13-Jan 14-Jan 15-Jan
1                 V     V     V     V                             S      S      S      S      S      S
2           S     S
```

The only solution I have so far discovered is doing something like this:

```
=IFERROR(
  LOOKUP(2,
         1/(FILTER(
              FILTER(Tabel1,
                     Tabel1[[Personal ID]:[Personal ID]]=$A2),
              Tabel1[#Headers]="Start")<=B$1)/
           (FILTER(
              FILTER(Tabel1,
                     Tabel1[[Personal ID]:[Personal ID]]=$A2),
              Tabel1[#Headers]="End")>=B$1),
         FILTER(
           FILTER(Tabel1,
                  Tabel1[[Personal ID]:[Personal ID]]=$A2),
           Tabel1[#Headers]="Code")),
"")
```

The code does exactly what is asked but I need to repeat this code for the entire year and for hundreds of IDs which completely crashes the Excel. I am wondering if there is a more sophisticated way.

P.S.: I am quite sure it is possible to do this with a pivot table but the problem is that I want to prevent having to manually press a refresh button

Comment: Welcome! What should you do if the date ranges accidentally overlap? Print the first value encountered? Last thing? Print all separated by a comma `V, S`?

Comment: Hello! It is actually a bit more complex than that.. If there is an overlap `s` should always show instead of `v`, but they can appear in any order. I hadn't reached that point yet in my attempt to code this but if you can integrate this it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like

`{=TEXTJOIN("";1;IF((Tabel1[Personal ID]=$A2)*(Tabel1[Start]<=C$1)*(Tabel1[End]>=C$1);Tabel1[Code];""))}`

Perhaps wrapped in two SUBSTITUTE() or REGEX() to replace `VS` and `SV` with `V` (Or just highlight cells with two or more characters using Conditional Formatting)

Unfortunately, I can't check if the formula works in Excel - my version doesn't yet know the [**TEXTJOIN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c). Maybe it should be

`{=TEXTJOIN("";1;IF((Tabel1[Personal ID]=$A2)*(Tabel1[Start]<=C$1)*(Tabel1[End]>=C$1)=1;Tabel1[Code];""))}`